# Accept options when installing Java in terminal

Tags: software-installation, openjdk

How can I install Java (OpenJDK) on an Ubuntu system with regional preferences set int the command itself, so that it runs through the complete setup without needing user input? I am using this command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y
```

This always waits for input where I have to select preference for region, where I select `1` for **Americas** and then `85` for **Los_Angeles**. Can I include this as a part of a command somehow, so that I can automate this?

Comment: Is the Java application you're running a UI-based tool or does it run as a service? 

Comment: Not sure how it matters. The question is about installing Java itself, what Java applications run after that doesn't matter.

Comment: It matters because if you don't need the UI stuff, you can install the "headless" JDK, which doesn't ask for region.

Comment: Ah, did not know that! Yes, then a headless will work perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). It is a program that simulates terminal input in programs that interactively ask for data. Great tool for automation. You can install it with `sudo apt install expect`.

Because I don't know what exact questions the openjdk installer asks, I would use a fictional example of a program `someprogram` that asks two questions, `Enter your name:` and `Enter your age:` and then does something (not asking for any more input). If you want to automatically provide answers to these questions, the script will look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn someprogram
expect "name:"
send "John\r"
expect "age:"
send "42\r"
wait
```

The `spawn` command runs your program, `expect` tells the script to wait until the specified string appears in the program output, `send` tells the script to send specified string to the program (`\r` is Enter), and `wait` waits until the program terminates.