# How can I write in a shell setup with a script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, teamviewer

I want to automate my installation of teamviewer. I can set up teamviewer using the command `teamviewer setup` which runs in the gnome shell and asks me for the credentials. I would like to be able to automate this in a script and not have to enter the credentials by hand.

I have already use command like:

```
$ printf "xxxxx\nxxxx" | teamviewer setup
```

But didn't work.

Any solutions ?

[teamviewer setup command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clj5U.png)

Comment: You really need to explain in more detail what it is you want to achieve, it's not clear from your question. What exactly does the setup script need to do?

Comment: Sorry I'm not good in English. I want to automate my installation of teamviewer. I can set up teamviewer using the command "$ teamviewer setup" which runs in the gnome shell and asks me for the credentials. I would like to be able to automate this in a script and not have to enter the credentials by hand.

Comment: Is `teamviewer setup` command asking you for credentials on the terminal or via some GUI window?

Comment: On the terminal.

Comment: @laoduille Then you can use `expect` to automate this. See my recent answer to a very similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360835/accept-options-when-installing-java-in-terminal/1361425#1361425

Comment: I think this is the solution to my problem. I'm going to look this way. I keep informed if it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by the tool advised by [raj](https://askubuntu.com/users/1089525/raj). Thanks to him ! This tool is "Expect". https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be. An interpreted language provides branching and high-level control structures to direct the dialogue. In addition, the user can take control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning control to the script.

Example: (In my case)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn teamviewer setup   
expect "username:"          
send "xxxxxx\r"      
expect "password:"       
send "xxxxxx\r"     
wait
```